# FormatException (argument list mismatch) in interpolated String expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string, clr

In production, we encountered an issue which is not getting simulated anywhere else but it peaked my interest because of seemingly such error is impossible to happen (as far as I know !)

The application is ASP.NET based web app running on .Net framework 4.8 and IIS 10.

We have one log line which uses the string interpolation like following,

```
logger.Error(ex, $"The process {processId} on dataset {dataSetId} failed with error : {ex.Message}");
```

All the variables mentioned in interpolation are local variables and not null. This log line is in catch block and hence the exception *ex* can not be null.

Now we got the following error in production (so far got only once),

```
System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
at System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
at System.String.Format(String format, Object[] args)
....
```

This is a partial stack trace provided other lines may expose our proprietary code.

We tried to simulate this by throwing dummy exception from code but no success.

While going through the ildasm, I observed that the compiler converted string interpolation to System.String.Format overloaded method which takes three objects arguments,

```
public static string Format (string format, object? arg0, object? arg1, object? arg2);
```

Disassmbly,

```
      IL_00bb:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Format(string,
                                                              object,
                                                              object,
                                                              object)
```

However in the exception trace, it points to another overloaded method which is,

```
public static string Format (IFormatProvider? provider, string format, params object?[] args);
```

This is confusing and I suspect JIT compiler might be doing something but I doubt given it's a proven technology and tested very thoroughly.

Any pointer / help is appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: Does the stack trace point to the line of code you show? Normally that exception happens in a traditional call to `string.Format` with numeric place holders (like `{0}`) and an argument list

Comment: You have null data.  Why?  You probably got to different overloads in the exception because one except did a "throw" which caused a second exception to occur.

Comment: Correct @Flydog57 the exception is happening in string.Format and it happens when we try to format  string to log the error.
We don't have null data because two variables are integers and another is the exception which is caught in that catch block.

Comment: Your partial stack doesn't show whether  (or where) _your_ started the calls that caused the exception. This exception is the result of something like `string.Format("{0} to {1}", first);`, i.e.  the number of parameters not matching the number of `{N}` expressions. I've never seen it on an interpolated string (or because of a null). Are you very sure that line of code is the offending line?